# Captura de datos en input con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

estoy intentando capturar datos (procedentes desde PHP en realidad) en el value de un input oculto.

Tanto con javascript puro como con Jquery he intentado capturar esos datos para procesarlos después (en el ejemplo sólo los muestro por pantalla) y no hay manera.

Código HTML (pruebaValor.html):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="pruebaValor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id='prueba1' type="hidden" value="hola" /> <!--El value en realidad obtiene sus datos mediante un echo de PHP-->
</body>
</html>
```

Código Javascript (pruebaValor.js)

```
var x = document.getElementById('prueba1');
var y = $('#prueba1');;
console.log(x); //¿Por qué dice que es null?
console.log(x.value); //Al ser un null se obtiene un error cuando se accede a su valor.
console.log(y); //Me devuelve un objeto
console.log(y.val()); //Me devuelve indefinido.
console.log(y.attr('value')); //Y aquí también
```

Aunque en el ejemplo sólo los muestro por consola, en lo que estoy haciendo el objetivo es procesar esos datos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *procesar esos datos*? ¿Qué haces para *procesarlos*, dónde los *procesas*  y qué error tienes cuando los *procesas*?

Comment: Es que simplemente he puesto un código simplificado. El valor del imput se va a usar en realidad para una consulta AJAX.

Comment: En js puro si funciona, prueba a eliminar las lineas de jquery y te funciona. No te los devuelve porque te está dando un error, al eliminar esas lineas si que te lo devuelve

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el *script* está ejecutándose antes de que la vista haya sido renderizada.

```
var x = document.getElementById('prueba1');
```

En esta línea, `x` es `undefined` porque efectivamente aún no hay ningún elemento en el *DOM* que tenga por `id` *prueba1*. De hecho, no hay ninguno.

Hay dos formas de hacer esto.

1. Suscribirse al evento `load`
   `window` va a emitir un evento llamado `load` una vez se haya renderizado toda la vista. Por tanto, podemos suscribirnos a ese evento para entonces correr nuestro *script*

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const x = document.getElementById('prueba1');
    console.log(x); // HTMLElement
});
```

2. Diferir la ejecución del *script*
   La cual es la forma de hacer esto, realmente. Podemos incluir el tag `script` en el HTML del mismo modo pero con el atributo `defer`. Este atributo hace precisamente lo que buscamos: va a diferir la ejecución del *script* hasta que la vista esté renderizada.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pruebaValor.js" defer></script>
```

**pruebaValor.js**

```
const x = document.getElementById('prueba1');
console.log(x); // HTMLElement
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado. No me había dado cuenta de que el problema estaba al indicar que había un script antes de todo.